# Node Selenium WebdriverJS - How to check if element is truly clickable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to check if an element is truly clickable in selenium webdriverJS?

I know that I can check if element is displayed and if element is enabled. However, if the element is hidden by some other element, say for example, by a modal popup, it can't be clicked. In that case, I want webdriver to wait until the element is truly clickable.

How to do this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem and final found a solution. Even tho I'm using [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) instead of [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.org/package/selenium-webdriver), I think my solution might be useful for who ever is working on selenium with Node.js.

Basically, I use the generic `waitFor` together with an asserter to keep trying the click until it success or timeout. And here is the code

usage

```
browser
    .elementById('some-button')
    .clickWhenClickable()
```

methods.js

```
var wd = require('wd');
var asserters = require('./asserters');
wd.addElementPromiseMethod('clickWhenClickable', function clickWhenClickable (timeout, pollFreq) {
  return this.browser.waitFor(asserters.elementHasBeenClicked(this), timeout, pollFreq);
});
```

asserters.js

```
var wd = require('wd');
var Asserter = wd.Asserter;

exports.elementHasBeenClicked = function elementHasBeenClicked (el) {
  return new Asserter(function hasBeenClicked (browser, cb) {
    el.click(function(err) {
      cb(null, !err, null);
    });
  });
};
```